# Why products are not displayed on category page in Magento2.2.0?

Tags: magento2.2, migration

Products are not displayed on the category page.

I completed data migration process and also do clean cache and reindex process.

And also check stock, quantity, visibility and etc.

But still product not display.

Comment: did you checked for system logs ? 
If product is assigned to proper website/store ?

Comment: Please select all products and save it again.

Comment: Yes, I already check it. But not display product on the category page. **@Magento2Learner**

Comment: Have you checked your category in admin section is everything fine there and products are listed in edit category section.

Comment: Yes, I checked category in the admin panel. But I do not know what is the problem. **@AmritPalSingh**

Comment: You can take reference from here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158646/magento-2-products-not-showing-in-category-but-are-visible-via-search/177437#177437

Comment: No, It is not work for me. I tried all possibility regarding to product and category but i not get any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please follow all the steps which are given in this link @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/2493774/8167656

Also, Can you please check the placeholder path and placeholder image configuration is properly set and it must be exist on /pub/media/catalog/product/images/placeholder/

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset indexer once

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

And reindex again and clear cache

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I try this so many time but not working.

Comment: did you tried to trace issue where collection loads ? 
You may debug there why products are not loading in collection based on that you can trace the actual issue.

Comment: Yes, I checked product collection get on the category page(list.phtml).But I do not know why products are not displayed.?